# How to force a docker-compose container to rebuild when yarn dependencies have changed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, build, yarnpkg

We have a Dockerized environment with a Vue application running through a Vite dev server in its own `node:lts`-based container.

I set up a Dockerfile that, during build, copies over our Vue application codebase and has a `RUN yarn install` directive to get the dependencies installed.

That way, our docker-compose.yml configuration for that container points to that Dockerfile in the "build" section, and I can just have an entrypoint running `yarn dev`.

**When a developer adds or removes a dependency in our package.json file, it would be great if the `docker-compose up -d` command could identify that something has changed and automatically re-run the build step,** installing any new packages.

But I cannot seem to figure out how to accomplish this without making a wrapper script for `docker-compose up -d` and telling people to use that.

It seems like it would be possible to somehow get Yarn's checksum and maybe specify that as a "build" section arg. I think, then, Docker would see that the arg has changed and require a rebuild, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you `docker-compose up -d --build` then it will rebuild everything that has a `build:` block, and Docker's layer-caching rules will apply from here.

Comment: There's a common Node setup that stores the `node_modules` tree in an anonymous volume, however, and if you use this then it will ignore changes in the `package.json` file on rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a wrapper script you would need to trigger a rebuild every start. If the dockerfile is setup correctly, docker would then only rebuild the layer where the package.json changed.

As @david-maze pointed out this can be done with `docker-compose up -d --build`

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the layer-caching rules only apply when a build is triggered and, hence, it already does this. But are there not times when simply doing `docker-compose up` identifies that a build is required? Because ideally I could hook into that somehow. I suspect I'm going to have to go the wrapper script route either way.